# NextJS optimistic update on server component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a server component  that displays a list of things; this list is obtained by doing a db query (mysql2 library). I then have a client component  that adds a thing to the list when the user clicks a button by calling a POST route handler which does an insert db query and returns the newly added thing.

How can I optimistically update the server component's list of things as soon as the button is clicked on the client and before the db query runs? At this point (on button click and before db query), I know what the newly added thing will be and can assume that it will be successfully added to the list.

I want to keep the server component as a server component if possible, but please let me know if this is not possible. I am basically asking if there is a way to update the server component's list of things from the route handler and before the db insert query runs (so not doing another db query to get the new list of things)

Please let me know if there is any way to accomplish this or if I am thinking about this all wrong. Or any suggestions at all. Thank you!

Comment: if you need JS code for the server but to run on the client, then you are dealing with a client component, because you will need to hydrate this part of the code. Then in the client components you have the `useOptimistic` hook.